# form not being hidden on page for a lit-element application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I am working with a udemy.com video and have posted this question with no response so I am posting here to see if i can get some insight into my issue. I am using Lit-element 2.0rc and working on building a Personal phonebook app.

The scope of the project is that I have a form that can be called as a popup when the add a contact link is clicked. I have it set up with the properties for the popup and the button click is working. What is not working at the moment is the popup itself as I still have the form visible on my page and I am not sure how to make it disappear so that the form can be called through the popup property. I would like to have someone look at my code and let me know if there is anything that I need to change so that the form remains hidden until the button is clicked to bring it up as a popup here is the code I am working with

```
  App.js  
  import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
  import SideMenu from './SideMenu.js';
  import ContentArea from './ContentArea.js';

  class PhoneBook extends LitElement{

   constructor(){
       super();
       this.popupOpen = false;
   }

   togglePopup(){
       console.log('clicked button');
       console.log(this.popupOpen);
       this.popupOpen = !this.popupOpen;
       console.log(this.popupOpen);
       this.requestUpdate();
   }

   render(){
       return html `
       <style>
       .main-page{
           display: grid;
           grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
       }
       </style>
       <div class="main-page">
           <side-menu .togglePopup="${this.togglePopup}"></side-menu>
           <content-area popupOpen="${this.popupOpen}" .togglePopup="${this.togglePopup}"> 
  </content-area>
       </div>


       `;
     }
  }

  customElements.define('phone-book', PhoneBook)

  Sidemenu.js
  import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element'

  export default class SideMenu extends LitElement{

   constructor(){
       super();
   }

   static get properties(){
       return{
           togglePopup: Function
       }
   }

   render(){
       return html `
       <style>
       @import './css/global.css';
       #side-menu{
           background: #323759;
           height: 100vh;
           padding: 50px 25px
       }
       .logo{
           text-align:center;
       }
       .logo img{
           width: 100px;
       }
       .title{
           font-weight: 700;
           color: #ccced7;
           margin: 1rem 0;
       }
       #side-menu nav a {
           color: #ccced7;
           text-decoration: none;
           text-transform: capitalize;
           display: block;
           padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
       }
       #side-menu nav a span.icon{
           padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
       }
       </style>
       <section id="side-menu">
           <div class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png"></div>
           <div class="menu">
               <div class="title">Contacts</div>
               <nav>
                   <a href="#" @click="${this.togglePopup}"><span class="icon">+</span>Add 
  Contact</a>
                   <a href="#"><span class="icon">+</span>Add Contact</a>
                   <a href="#"><span class="icon">+</span>Add Contact</a>
                   <a href="#"><span class="icon">+</span>Add Contact</a>
               </nav>
           </div>
       </section>
       `;
     }
  }

  customElements.define('side-menu', SideMenu)

   contentArea.js
   import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
   import ContactsList from '../components/ContactsList.js';
   import FavoritesList from '../components/FavoritesList';
   import FormPopup from '../components/FormPopup';
   export default class ContentArea extends LitElement{

   constructor(){
       super();
   }

   static get properties(){
       return{
           popupOpen: Boolean,
           togglePopup: Function
       }
   }

   render(){
       return html `
       <style>
       @import './css/global.css';
       #content-area{
           background: #fcfdff;
           padding: 50px 80px;
       }
       </style>
       <section id="content-area">
           <form-popup .popupOpen="${this.popupOpen}" .togglePopup="${this.togglePopup}"> 
    </form-popup>
           <favorites-list></favorites-list>
           <contacts-list></contacts-list>
       </section>
       `;
       }
    }

    customElements.define('content-area', ContentArea)

    Formpopup.js
    import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element'
    import ContactsList from '../components/ContactsList.js'
    import FavoritesList from '../components/FavoritesList'

    export default class FormPopup extends LitElement{

   constructor(){
       super();
   }

   static get properties(){
       return{
           popupOpen: Boolean
       }
   }

   render(){
       return html `
       <style>
       @import './css/global.css';
       .form-popup{
           background: #2b304c;
           height: 100vh;
           width: 100vw;
           position: fixed;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           visibility: hidden;
           transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
           opacity: 0
       }
       .form-popup.active{
           visibility: visible;
           opacity: 1;
       }
       form{
           width: 400px;
           background: white;
           padding: 20px;
           border-radius: 10px;
           display: grid;
           grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
           grid-gap: 20px;
       }
       h2{
           font-size: 1.4rem;
           font-weight: 500;
           grid-column: 1/5;
       }
       .form-group{
           padding: 0;
       }
       label{
           font-size: .7rem;
           background: white;
           position: relative;
           top: 7px;
           display: inline-block;
       }
       input[type="text"]{
           padding: 10px;
           display: block;
           width: 100%;
       }
       .first-name{
           grid-column: 1/3;
       }
       .last-name{
           grid-column: 3/5;
       }
       .address-1{
           grid-column: 1/5;
       }
       .address-2{
           grid-column: 1/5;
       }
       .city{
           grid-column: 1/3
       }
       .button{
           justify-self: end;
           grid-column: 4/5;
       }
       .button button{
           cursor: pointer;
           padding: 10px 25px;
           background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
           background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
           background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10- 
    25,Safari5.1-6 */
           background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, 
    FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
           border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
           color: white;
           border-radius: 5px;
           text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
       }
       .close-btn{
           position: absolute;
           z-index: 3;
           right: 30px;
           top: 0;
           font-size: 2rem;
           padding: 20px;
           color:white;
       }
       .close-btn svg{
          width: 24px;
          height: 24px;
       }
       </style>
       <section className="form-popup${(this.popupOpen) ? ' active' : ''}">
           <form>
               <div class="close-btn" @click="${this.togglePopup}"><svg 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data- 
    prefix="fas"
                data-icon="times" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-11" role="img" 
    viewBox="0 0 352 512"><path fill="currentColor"
                d="M242.72 256l100.07-100.07c12.28-12.28 12.28-32.19 0-44.48l-22.24- 
   22.24c-12.28-12.28-32.19-12.28-44.48 0L176 189.28
                75.93 89.21c-12.28-12.28-32.19-12.28-44.48 0L9.21 111.45c-12.28 12.28- 
   12.28 32.19 0 44.48L109.28 256 9.21 356.07c-12.28
                12.28-12.28 32.19 0 44.48l22.24 22.24c12.28 12.28 32.2 12.28 44.48 0L176 
    322.72l100.07
                100.07c12.28 12.28 32.2 12.28 44.48 0l22.24-22.24c12.28-12.28 12.28-32.19 
    0-44.48L242.72 256z"/></svg></div>
               <h2>Add a new contact</h2>
               <div class="form-group first-name">
                   <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="first_name">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group last-name">
                   <label for="first_name">Last Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="last_name">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group address-1">
                   <label for="first_name">Address #1</label>
                   <input type="text" name="address_1">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group address-2">
                   <label for="first_name">Address #2</label>
                   <input type="text" name="address_2">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group city">
                   <label for="first_name">City</label>
                   <input type="text" name="city">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group state">
                   <label for="first_name">State</label>
                   <input type="text" name="state">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group zipcode">
                   <label for="first_name">zipcode</label>
                   <input type="text" name="zipcode">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group button">
                   <button type="submit">Add</button>
               </div>
           </form>
       </section>
       `;
   }
}

customElements.define('form-popup', FormPopup)
```

Again what is suppose to happen is the hidden form can be called by clicking the add a new contact  link and that is not happening because the form it’s self is still showing on the page and not being hidden as it should be .

Thanks for any help that is given.

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing . for one of the properties once that was filled in the app is working as intended .